# Unix - which application is in the foreground?

Tags: python, linux, unix, redhat

I need to be able to determine if a certain application/binary in Unix is running in the foreground.

I do not want to look at CPU utilization or memory utilization because technically the application could be in the background and performing a long running task.

I'm not necessarily interested in code samples.  Is this something that can be achieved using Python or some other scripting library?

Comment: If you use `subprocess.Popen` to spawn the process, then you could use [Popen.poll](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.poll) to check if it is running.

Comment: Does the program use X or the console?

Comment: What does it mean "running in the foreground"? Do you mean if the application has focus or something like that?

Comment: Bakuriu - yes, I'd like to determine if the application has focus.

Comment: Dietrich - I will try to find more information to answer your question.  This is running on Redhat.  I believe it's started using console.

Comment: This is aimed at Windows, but the concept applies reasonably to other systems: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/08

Comment: "Focus" is a function of the window manager, not the program.  Determining which process has "the focus" will depend on the windowing system you are using (XWindows?) and the particular desktop/window manager (KDE, Gnome, XFCE, etc?)  Even the concept of "focus" is fuzzy, as in X focus can move with the mouse pointer.

Answer (score -2):

I highly recommend the python package [psutil](http://pythonhosted.org/psutil/#processes) which is ideal for system getting information about spawned and all other processes. The method `is_running()` of a process object appears to be the one you want.

Comment: `is_running` can return true for background processes; a return value of `False` simply means it is sleeping or otherwise idle, not that it is in the foreground.

Comment: In that case you would need to find the terminal it was invoked from ( .parent() ), the clue is in the "waiting channel" that the parent has. If it is waiting for a process running in the foreground, the channel is sys_rt_sigsuspend, if it is waiting for user input (i.e., the process is in the background), the channel is n_tty_read. This channel is stored in /proc/<ID>/wchan where <ID> is the process ID. You won't be able to tell from this whether your process is in the background, and the shell is now waiting for a new foreground process.